# How can I declare an empty int

Tags: java, android-studio, int

I want to declare an empty `int` like you would do with a String:  `String userName ="";` 
I need an empty int because I want to select a (random) picture from an array:

```
public int[] mBackground = {
       R.drawable.heart,
       R.drawable.cane,
       R.drawable.watch
};
```

This is the code I use to get a random picture from the array:

```
public int getBackground(){
int background = "";
    Random generate = new Random();
    int randomNumber = generate.nextInt(mBackground.length);

    background = mBackground[randomNumber];

    return background;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question. Why do you need to initialize it? You don't even need the variable.

This code works as you want

```
public int getBackground(){
    Random generate = new Random();
    int randomNumber = generate.nextInt(mBackground.length);
    return mBackground[randomNumber];
}
```

However, if you want to have a variable you can do

```
public int getBackground(){
    Random generate = new Random();
    int randomNumber = generate.nextInt(mBackground.length);
    int background = mBackground[randomNumber];
    return background;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you must assign your `int background` variable a default value for some reason, `-1` is often workable. You cannot assign an `int` variable to anything other than an integer value (`""` is a `String` so won't work).

```
    int background = -1;
    // ...
    if (background < 0) {
        // handle invalid value, perhaps assign a default
    }
```

If you need your variable to point to "nothing", consider using the boxed type `Integer`, which you can initialize to `null`.

```
    Integer background = null; // will throw NullPointerException if unboxed to int
```

Otherwise, don't declare the variable until you're ready to assign it. That way you don't have to give it a pointless initial value.

```
    int background = mBackground[randomNumber];
```

Or you could just return the value straight from your method instead of assigning it to an intermediate variable.

```
    return mBackground[randomNumber];
```

You actually don't have to initialize a local variable at all when you declare it. This is perfectly acceptable.

```
    int background;
```

However, you must assign a value before you can use it.

Here's the shortest statement of your method's intention.

```
public int getBackground(){
    return mBackground[new Random().nextInt(mBackground.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an empty int in the context you have given, an empty string is a String containing a sequence of 0 length. int is a primitive data type and can't take any value outside the parameters of either a signed or unsigned 32-bit integer unless you want to declare as an Integer boxed Object in which case you can declare it as null.

For a method as simple as selecting a random value from an array you may as well just use a one-liner.

```
public int getBackground(){
    return mBackground[new Random().nextInt(mBackground.length)];
}
```